# Sublime Text Shortcut with arguments (Cut from, Paste to)

Tags: vim, plugins, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

I'm trying to figure out if ST has this certain functionality that exists in Vim. Basically I want to be able, to tell sublime which line to cut from, the amount of lines and the location of where to paste it.

I've extended my sublime's functionality quite a lot with various packages but I can't seem to be able to find the equivalent of what I describe above. Is there such package or plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `:t`, `:m` and `:d`, [VintageEx](https://github.com/SublimeText/VintageEx) is what you are looking for: it adds a command-line similar to the one in Vim. It doesn't have *all* of Vim's Ex commands but those three commands are there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer romainl! Reading through VintageEx documentation, it's clear I'll need to switch on Vintage mode, which is what I was trying to avoid for the time being (will make the switch later down the line :-) ). So I assume the only way to get that functionality is through either Vintage mode or perhaps through building these bindings or a package myself? Those would be the two options, correct?

Comment: I don't use Sublime Text myself so don't take my word on it but yeah, I think those are your only options.